# I'm not able to access the attributes of my class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm creating a User Interface using PyQt4 module . the problem i'am facing is that i'm not able to access "self.ftp_tableWidget" variable

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(790, 610)
    self.FTP = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.FTP.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("FTP"))
    self.ftp_tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.FTP)
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 411, 192))
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(331, 0))
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ftp_tableWidget"))
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setRowCount(31)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    self.update_table()
```

This where the ftp_tableWidget is intialized.

```
  def update_table(self):
    cursor.execute('''SELECT MAX(SNO) FROM ftp_auth_table1''')
    entry=cursor.fetchall()
    entry=entry[0]
    count=entry[0]
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setRowCount(count)
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM ftp_auth_table1''')
    entry=cursor.fetchall()
```

This is the code that updates the table widget.

```
 def adding(self):
    self.msg=add_to()
    self.msg.show()
```

This piece of code is calling a class which adds data to the database.

```
class add_to(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(add_to,self).__init__()
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
```

This piece of code is initializes the class which appends data to the database and calls the update_table function to update the table widget .

This the Error that im getting

```
    self.ftp_tableWidget.setRowCount(count)
    AttributeError: 'add_to' object has no attribute 'ftp_tableWidget'
```

specs :
im using python 2.7 and PyQt4 module .

after editing the code according to the answere given by "notbad jpeg":
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
       def **init**(self,mainwindow):
        self.setupUi(mainwindow)
       def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

this is giving me a problem :

```
class add_to(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
    super(add_to,self).__init__()
    self.window=QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.MainWindow=Ui_MainWindow(self.window)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self,self.MainWindow)
```

this gives an error:

```
MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'setObjectName'
```

Pls can anyone help Me .

Thanx in advance

Comment: Does `Ui_MainWindow.__init__()` call `setupUi()`?

Comment: Blckknght: no it doesn't , Thanx for noticing.

Comment: I changed the code a bit now there is a __init__ in my Ui_MainWindow

Comment: @thecreator232, can you update your code in the question to reflect your changes?

Comment: I edited my answer for your change, I think it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That comment is stating your problem. You need to add an `__init__()` method to your `Ui_MainWindow` class that calls `self.setupUi()`so that everything in your `setupUi()` gets called right away when you call `super()`.

Edit: So now that you changed your code a bit and you're getting the `__init__()` takes two arguments error, I looked around and saw your inline code that shows that you need to pass a `MainWindow` argument to your `Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self, MainWindow)`. And then, pass that `MainWindow` to your `setupUi` method.

Edit #2: Change

```
class add_to(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       super(add_to,self).__init__()
       self.window=QtGui.QMainWindow()
       self.MainWindow=Ui_MainWindow(self.window)
       Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self,self.MainWindow)
```

to...

```
class add_to(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       super(add_to,self).__init__()
       self.window=QtGui.QMainWindow()
       self.MainWindow=Ui_MainWindow(self.window)
```

The call to `Ui_MainWindow.__init__()` was redundant, since it gets called automatically when you create and instance of the class: `self.MainWindow=Ui_MainWindow(self.window)`. Plus, you were passing an instance of itself as an argument to itself.

Comment: okay i did what u told i created an __init__ in my Ui_MainWindow but it still shows the same problem.

when i put a Ui_MainWindow.__init__() ,in my add_to class.
its asking for a instance of Ui_MainWindow

Pls Help

Comment: yah that is true ,but i have unable to find a solution for it .

Comment: can u tell me how can i overcome this problem .

thanking u in advance

Comment: i edited the code again now when the add_to class trys to intialize the Ui_MainWindow, it gives an error.I have edited the code above.

Comment: :your code solved the second problem but the initial Error still exists . i still cant use ftp_tableWidget.

Comment: I think your problem is becoming your maze of subclassing and objects.  If you try to simplify it more and more I think it will work. At the moment i don't see a need for your `add_to` class at all.

Comment: is there any way to open a popup without defining it in class.

or will nesting of classes help in this situation

Comment: to get the feel of how Qt works in python, you should use the gui to put a dummy UI together, then look at the python code it generates.

Comment: yeah i'm doin that. thanx for ur help

Comment: gui's are a rough place to start with python, i gave up and switched to guis through html5, way more reasonable.good luck though

Comment: i have done a bit of coding with python , but this my first big project in python, and my first gui